# Why can't I upvote this comment?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, comments, up-votes

I tried to upvote this comment on Area51 and the following was displayed:

[image]

What's going on here? Why can't I upvote it? Did I miss something? I've never seen this message before.

Comment: I have seen this several times before when a comment (or its parent post) has been deleted in the meanwhile. But since it's posted on Nov 16, I don't think that this is the case. Press F5 to be sure.

Comment: Same thing. Can't touch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shouldn't have been showing upvote & flag icons beside comments for proposals that have advanced past the definition phase. They're gone now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out!

It seems like the proposal is now in the *commitment* stage and all of the comments are locked. I don't know how I missed that, but I think the error message could be worded a little differently to indicate this.